# TCP DUP ACK sent on retransmission

Tags: linux, tcp

I am seeing an issue in a TCP connection where the receiver, when it receives a retransmission from the server (due to timeout), will send a DUP ACK to the server in response to the retransmission.

This is strange as I have assumed that DUP ACK is sent only when an out of order packet is received, and this is for the other side to do fast retransmit. Has anyone seen this behavior?

[image]

Comment: What issue? If it wasn't acknowledged it would be retransmitted again. Ttere is no problem here.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)